# Regular Expressions for string Contains pattern

Tags: regex

Am trying to form Regex for the below pattern for string

```
String may contain alphanumeric characters
String may contain the following special characters like Space ( ) - :/
```

If the string contains anything apart from this my Regex should return false

I have tried with below regex `[0-9a-zA-Z\s():-]+` but it is not working out. match is returning true even if it contais characters like **,;** etc

am able to achieve for blacklisting but am trying to achieve what characters are allowed if anything othet than that found return false

Some one who is good in writing regular expressions can help me out.

Thanks

Comment: I dono why -1. tried but not able get exact answer and i posted for querys !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to use start/end anchors to avoid matching unwanted input data:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z \/():-]+$
```

Comment: i have updated my contains  list alphanumeric Space ( ) - :/

Comment: Technically you include any whitespace (`\s`), not just a space.

Comment: @anubhava Thanks..am not able to figure out how to include backward slash to contains list

Comment: @anubhava my bad..i need to include forward slash as valid. like Hotel/FBO(a-b):  should be valid